# Использование буквы "ё" на сайте в интерфейсе, справке и т.д., вне сообщений/комментариев участников

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация, ё

[Понятно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3671/176217), что нет особого смысла править пользовательские сообщения для замены "е" на "ё". Но мне кажется стоит придерживаться общей позиции по этому вопросу в текстах самого сайта. Например, в Справке или других предложениях, которые не являются частью вопросов/ответов пользователей.
В частности, был [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3050/176217) о необходимости замены "е" на "ё" и он был удовлетворён. Какое ваше мнение: стоит ли придерживаться единого стиля во всех внутренних документах сайта?

Нашел ответ в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3158/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F#comment10073_3158), но хотелось бы видеть это именно как ответ, для закрепления точки зрения, так сказать.

***Обновление:*** Пожалуйста, будьте внимательны! Ссылка на предлагаемый дубликат есть в самом вопросе и тут же объяснено в чём именно разница. Сейчас речь о сообщениях в служебной части сайта, а не о редактировании предлагаемых правок.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, этот вопрос рассматривался одновременно с решением об использовании «вы»/«Вы». Если кто-то найдёт оригинал рассмотриения, просьба запостить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Косметические правки. "вы -> Вы", "е -> ё"](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3668/%d0%9a%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%92%d1%8b-%d0%b5-%d1%91)

Comment: @pavel штоа, опять? :-D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В интерфейсе сайта и статьях справки мы договаривались писать насколько возможно грамотным русским языком. И во множестве мест уже используется буква «ё».

Если это явно нигде не закреплено, давайте уже закрепим.

Comment: Если это действительно так, то нужно пройтись по transifex и заменить как минимум все `еще` на `ещё` и в нужных местах `все` на `всё`.

Comment: "Закрепим" что? Не могли бы вы явно указать: «локализированные части сайта используют `ё`» (как (по памяти) правила языка советуют для материалов, рассчитанных на детей и иностранцев). Сообщения/комментарии участников—по желанию самих участников `ё` используется (как в [предыдущем обсуждении договорились](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3671/176217))

Answer (score 2):

Поправил где мог в transifex `е` на `ё`. Руководствовался списком [отсюда](http://www.yomaker.ru/yoslovar.htm).