# Жизненный цикл вопроса-дубликата

Tags: поддержка, дубликаты

Если кто-то (с достаточной репутацией) считает, что вопрос должен быть закрыт как дубликат существующего, он выполняет определенный ряд действий, после чего у автора вопроса в шапке вопроса появляется подобный баннер:

[image: это не решило проблему]

и дополнительно - автоматически сгенерированный комментарий от инициатора закрытия, вида:

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: Название_ранее_существующего вопроса

Допустим, я не хочу редактировать вопрос, т.к. ответил закрыватору в комментарии. Свой автосгенерированный комментарий он удалил, что намекает на то, что он отозвал свой голос на закрытие. Хотя я в этом и не уверен.

Что можно сделать, чтобы упомянутый баннер пропал из [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3960/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%91-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5) не прибегая к его редактированию?
Как вообще ведет себя система в этом случае?

Comment: ЕМНИП, надо дождаться окончания голосования за закрытие.

Comment: @PavelMayorov даже если закрыватор отозвал свой голос и других закрываторов не было?

Comment: удаление комментария != отзыву голоса. А отзыв голоса != прекращению голосования.

Comment: @PavelMayorov по первому пункту - понятно. По второму - странно. Почему так? Еще интересно: удаляется ли комментарий при отзыве голоса или нет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov кстати мой коммент тут тоже пропал. Модерация пока молчит.

Comment: Голосов за закрытие на вопросе нет на данный момент.

Comment: @Qwertiy а баннер всё же есть.