# В сообщении о нормах нужно заменить "е" на "ё"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нормы-поведения, ё

Вроде договаривались, что в интерфейсе везде будем употреблять "ё": [Использование буквы "ё" на сайте в интерфейсе, справке и т.д., вне сообщений/комментариев участников](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/15479).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В трансе этой строки не нашёл.

Нужно изменить в словах:

- увлеч**ё**нных
- обновл**ё**нных

Comment: Да вообще какая-то сомнительная фраза - как будто я сейчас не в нём нахожусь?

Comment: Само наличие баннера сомнительное. Торчащие из каждого угла сайта ссылки на эти Нормы довольно раздражительны. Не хватает ещё звукового сопровождения и анимации.

Comment: Круче всего этот баннер смотрится на самом странице Норм :)