# В слове "учетная" заменить "е" на "ё" в справке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, ё

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/account

Напоминаю: [Использование буквы "ё" на сайте в интерфейсе, справке и т.д., вне сообщений/комментариев участников](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/15479).

Так что, во всех вложенных разделах справки раздела "Моя учётная запись" в слове **учетная** заменить **е** на **ё**. Это относится и к заголовкам, и к словам, встречающимся в тексте самих статей.

Comment: @Qwertiy не завершено же!

Comment: @älёxölüt, тьфу.. Я в заголовке посмотрел и не прочитал, что тут про вложенные разделы говорится.

Comment: @Qwertiy надо картинок добавить. А вообще хорошо бы ответы писать при изменении статуса. Тут, кстати, флаг чей-то прилетел или самодеятельность сработала?

Comment: @älёxölüt, только [это](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=47884012#47884012) - я оба вопроса глянул и статус поставил)

Comment: @Qwertiy нет веры головоногим!

Comment: @älёxölüt пора делать такояки.