# Отсутствие перевода для всплывающего сообщения при отзыве голоса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов

Заметил что нет перевода для данного всплывающего сообщения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

Are you sure? If you retract, you won’t be able to vote to close this question again. - [Вы уверены? Если вы отзовете свой голос, то больше не сможете проголосовать за закрытие этого вопроса.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16768)

Comment: [Используем **ё** в переводах](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3960/176217). Подправил и утвердил.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо, не знал про ё :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, опять перевод слетел. сейчас там: «Retract your vote to delete? You won't be able to vote again on this post.»

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin [подправил](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17045). Не стесняйтесь предлагать собственные переводы через traducir.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я бы и рад, но у меня со школы большие трудности в написании сочинений. т.е. во внятном и стройном изложении своих мыслей.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin мне почему-то кажется, что дело немного в ДРУГОМ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, хм. я заинтригован. что же это за «другое»? стеснительность? лень? страх? зловредность? неосиляторство? «небарскоеэтодело»? теряюсь в догадках.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а, догадался! там надо употреблять БОЛЬШИЕ БУКВЫ? так это не проблема.